# Custom select box field in form from model in django

Tags: python, django

Please help me to do custom Select Box in forms of Django.

I want to query the data from the model,  i have created

In `Model.py`

`Title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=250, blank=True, null=True, help_text='Enter Title'`)

in `Admin.py`

```
class Meta:
        model = Book1
        fields = ['Title']

        Title = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Book1.objects.values_list('Title', flat=True).distinct(), widget=forms.Select())


class Book1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = Book1Form
    save_as = True


admin.site.register(Book1, Book1Admin)
```

But it did not display as a select box, only as a text field in the place of Tile field. Do I need to create custom select field for the QuerySet?

Answer (score 1):

Try placing your field definition outside `meta` just in case:

```
title = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Book1.objects.values_list('Title', flat=True).distinct(), widget=forms.Select())
class Meta:
        model = Book1
        fields = ['title']
```

I think Django is using your model's field instead of the custom one you added in your form.

Comment: Thank you So much Hagyn. it works!! I have another doubt is there any problem more than 100 records with ModelChoice Field

Comment: There is no problem, but have in mind that the page will load slowly and your users will have to search in a 100 option selector. There are some options to avoid this, you could try to implement a select2 selector. Check this Django app: https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html